# Image carousel with popup image

Tags: html, css, popup, carousel

I have a carousel with four images three images appreaing in a container, when hover on carousel image there on some text is showing but I would like to when click on image the image will pop-up with some caption text. I need popup image with text for the my carousel section or someone have 3 carousel images in container with popup image with text please suggest. please check thank in advance!

```css
#main-carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #0000001f;
}

#main-carousel h5 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-animation: leftToRight 1s ease-in-out .5s;
          animation: leftToRight 1s ease-in-out .5s;
}

#main-carousel h2 {
  font-size: 6.6rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: inherit;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  -webkit-animation: topToBottom 1s linear .3s;
          animation: topToBottom 1s linear .3s;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-caption {
  right: 15%;
  bottom: unset;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: left;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-control-next,
#main-carousel .carousel-control-prev {
  top: 50%;
  bottom: unset;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 4%;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: 5s all;
  transition: 5s all;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-control-next {
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-control-prev {
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

#main-carousel .btn-info {
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  font-family: "helveticaregular";
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

#main-carousel .btn-info::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 63px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* home blog slider */

.tile{
  width:100%;
  height:370px;
  background-color:#000000;
  display:inline-block;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
  overflow:hidden;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  
}
.tile img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.tile .text{
/*   z-index:99; */
  position:absolute;
  padding:30px;
  height:calc(100% - 0px);
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
}
.tile h3{
 font-weight:600;
  margin:0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  
}
.tile h4{
  font-weight:100;
  margin:20px 0 0 0;
  font-style:italic;
   transform: translateX(200px);
}
.tile p{
  font-weight:100;
  margin:20px 0 0 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding-top:10%;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:left;
}
.animate-text{
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;  
}
.tile:hover{
/*   background-color:#99aeff; */
box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
  transform:scale(1.05);
}
.tile:hover img{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.tile:hover .animate-text{
  transform:translateX(0);
  opacity:1;
}
.tile:hover span
{
  opacity:1;
  transform:translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="blog--slider-wrap blog--slider-main common-slider">
    
      <div class="blog-box">
           <div class="tile"> 
             <img src="images/image-1.jpg">
               <div class="text">
                     <p class="animate-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              
      <div class="blog-box">
           <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com">
           <img src="images/play-button.png" class="video-gallery">
           </a>
           <div class="tile"> 
             <img src="images/image-2.jpg">
                 </div>
              </div>
              
         <div class="blog-box">
           <div class="tile"> 
             <img src="images/image-3.jpg">
               <div class="text">
                     <p class="animate-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
         <div class="blog-box">
           <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com">
           <img src="images/play-button.png" class="video-gallery">
           </a>
           <div class="tile"> 
             <img src="images/image-4.jpg">
                 </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work, and check the "div.content" it will get the background of the carousel.

```js
$('.blog-box').on('click', function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  var text = $(this).find('p').text();
  
  $('#modal .content').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
  $('#modal p.carousel-text').text(text);
  $('#modal').show();
});

$('.close-modal').on('click', function(){
    $('#modal').hide();
});
```

```css
#main-carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #0000001f;
}

#main-carousel h5 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-animation: leftToRight 1s ease-in-out .5s;
          animation: leftToRight 1s ease-in-out .5s;
}

#main-carousel h2 {
  font-size: 6.6rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: inherit;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  -webkit-animation: topToBottom 1s linear .3s;
          animation: topToBottom 1s linear .3s;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-caption {
  right: 15%;
  bottom: unset;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: left;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-control-next,
#main-carousel .carousel-control-prev {
  top: 50%;
  bottom: unset;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 4%;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: 5s all;
  transition: 5s all;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-control-next {
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

#main-carousel .carousel-control-prev {
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

#main-carousel .btn-info {
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  font-family: "helveticaregular";
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

#main-carousel .btn-info::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 63px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* home blog slider */

.tile{
  width:100%;
  height:370px;
  background-color:#000000;
  display:inline-block;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
  overflow:hidden;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  
}
.tile img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.tile .text{
/*   z-index:99; */
  position:absolute;
  padding:30px;
  height:calc(100% - 0px);
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
}
.tile h3{
 font-weight:600;
  margin:0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  
}
.tile h4{
  font-weight:100;
  margin:20px 0 0 0;
  font-style:italic;
   transform: translateX(200px);
}
.tile p{
  font-weight:100;
  margin:20px 0 0 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding-top:10%;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:left;
}
.animate-text{
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;  
}
.tile:hover{
/*   background-color:#99aeff; */
box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
  transform:scale(1.05);
}
.tile:hover img{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.tile:hover .animate-text{
  transform:translateX(0);
  opacity:1;
}
.tile:hover span
{
  opacity:1;
  transform:translateY(0px);
}
#modal {
  display:none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="blog--slider-wrap blog--slider-main common-slider">
    <div class="blog-box">
        <div class="tile">
            <img src="images/image-1.jpg">
            <div class="text">
                <p class="animate-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-box">
        <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com">
        <img src="images/play-button.png" class="video-gallery">
        </a>
        <div class="tile"> 
            <img src="images/image-2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-box">
        <div class="tile">
            <img src="images/image-3.jpg">
            <div class="text">
                <p class="animate-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-box">
        <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com">
        <img src="images/play-button.png" class="video-gallery">
        </a>
        <div class="tile"> 
            <img src="images/image-4.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal">
  <div class="content">
      <p class="carousel-text"></p>
      <span class="close-modal">Close Modal</span>
  </div>
</div>
```